# Why errorHandler middlewear is getting called 2 time in express?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

function middleWear1(req, res, next) {
    throw Error()
}

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log("error handled");
    res.end("error occured at server")
}

app.use(middleWear1)
app.use(errorHandler)

app.get('/', middleWear1)

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("server is listening");
})
```

when I do localhost:8000 I get "error handled" printed two times in NodeJS terminal.

can some one explain why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you requested localhost:8000 through your web-browser, your browser will not only load `http://localhost:8000/` but `http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico` as well. This is default browser behaviour.

Now, since you've setup `middleWear1` to run for every request and the two requests are sent to your server, `error handled` gets printed twice to the console.

To answer you question from the comment:

In order to prevent `middleWear1` running for all requests and only for your `/` route, you can do:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

function middleWear1(req, res, next) {
    throw Error()
}

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log("error handled");
    res.end("error occured at server")
}

  
app.get('/', middleWear1) 
app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("server is listening");
})
```

Comment: Yes, I have just checked about this status and tried me. The browser runs like you said. But if we have to prevent that (example we want to add like the middleware), how do we prevent it ?